# How to set Visual Studio Filters for nested sub directory using cmake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, cmake

I have following structure

```
Main (dir)
      +-- CMakeLists.txt
      +-- File.cpp
      +-- File.hpp
      +-- Dir (dir)
          +-- CMakeLists.txt
          +-- File1.cpp
          +-- File1.hpp
          +-- File2.cpp
          +-- File2.hpp
```

**Main/CMakeLists.txt**

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED (VERSION 2.8.11)
PROJECT(Main)
FILE(GLOB SOURCE
    "*.hpp"
    "*.cpp"
)

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(Dir)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(Main ${SOURCE})
```

**Main/Dir/CmakeLists.txt**

```
FILE(GLOB LOCAL_SOURCE
    "*.hpp"
    "*.cpp"
)
SET(SOURCE
    ${SOURCE}
    ${LOCAL_SOURCE}
    PARENT_SCOPE
)
```

It generated the following structure in Visual Studio
[image]

**What I want:**

[image]  [image]

**What I tried:**

*Main/CMakeLists.txt*

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED (VERSION 2.8.11)
PROJECT(Main)
FILE(GLOB LOCAL_SOURCE
    "*.hpp"
    "*.cpp"
)

SET(SOURCE 
    ${LOCAL_SOURCE}
)

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(Dir)

SOURCE_GROUP(Main FILES ${LOCAL_SOURCE})
ADD_EXECUTABLE(Main ${SOURCE})
```

*Main/Dir/CmakeLists.txt*

```
FILE(GLOB LOCAL_SOURCE
    "*.hpp"
    "*.cpp"
)
SET(SOURCE
    ${SOURCE}
    ${LOCAL_SOURCE}
    PARENT_SCOPE
)

SOURCE_GROUP(Dir FILES ${LOCAL_SOURCE})
```

**What I get:**

[image]

Please help me regarding this.

- I do not want to use single CmakeFile.txt in Main directory having filters
- Actual structure is many layers deep nesting structure. So please suggest the solution which will work for any level sub directory

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are several ready to use or adaptable solutions out there to mimic a Source Tree behavior like in Eclipse with CMake for Visual Studio (e.g. [`ADD_SRC_SUBFOLDER DESTINATION_SRCS`](https://github.com/28msec/zorba/blob/master/cmake_modules/AddSrcSubfolder.cmake) from Zobra or [GroupSources](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2013-November/056332.html) from Luca).

Here is my reduced version for your use case:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.10)

project(Main CXX)

set(
    source_list
    "File.cpp"
    "File.hpp"
    "Dir/File1.cpp"
    "Dir/File1.hpp"
    "Dir/File2.cpp"
    "Dir/File2.hpp"
)

add_executable(Main ${source_list})

foreach(source IN LISTS source_list)
    get_filename_component(source_path "${source}" PATH)
    string(REPLACE "/" "\\" source_path_msvc "${source_path}")
    source_group("${source_path_msvc}" FILES "${source}")
endforeach()
```

See the documentation of [`source_group()`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command:source_group) that you have to give the sub-directories with double backslashes.

For the reason why I replaced your `file(GLOB ...)` with a dedicated list of all source files I like to quote from CMake's [`file()`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command:file) command documentation:

> We do not recommend using `GLOB` to collect a list of source files from
>   your source tree. If no CMakeLists.txt file changes when a source is
>   added or removed then the generated build system cannot know when to
>   ask CMake to regenerate.

And here is my fail-safe version (that checks for absolute paths) to be used as a function:

```
function(assign_source_group)
    foreach(_source IN ITEMS ${ARGN})
        if (IS_ABSOLUTE "${_source}")
            file(RELATIVE_PATH _source_rel "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}" "${_source}")
        else()
            set(_source_rel "${_source}")
        endif()
        get_filename_component(_source_path "${_source_rel}" PATH)
        string(REPLACE "/" "\\" _source_path_msvc "${_source_path}")
        source_group("${_source_path_msvc}" FILES "${_source}")
    endforeach()
endfunction(assign_source_group)
```

Which you would call in the example with

```
assign_source_group(${source_list})
```

Comment: It working but it is filtering as : E: > Code > Demo > Main > file.cpp & E: > Code > Demo > Main > Dir > file1.cpp

Comment: @Jai If you still want to use the `file(GLOB ...)` you need to add a `RELATIVE`. So in your case `file(GLOB_RECURSE source_list RELATIVE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}" "*.cpp" "*.hpp")`.

Comment: thank you, I achieved my requirement using some manipulation in you given cmake file.

Comment: Are you aware of any plans to support this out of the box in the future?

Comment: @lanoxx It's part of VS2017. You can now simply do `File/Open/Folder` with the folder containing your main `CMakeLists.txt` file.

Comment: It's an accepted answer but just as @Jai said, it doesn't do what the question asks.

Answer (score 22):

As of CMake [3.8, the `source_group` command offers a `TREE` argument](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/source_group.html) to recursively search the files paths of your sources, and structures the source groups to match your file system structure. Now, this offers a much cleaner solution:

```
project(Main)

set(SOURCE_LIST
    "File.cpp"
    "File.hpp"
    "Dir/File1.cpp"
    "Dir/File1.hpp"
    "Dir/File2.cpp"
    "Dir/File2.hpp"
)

add_executable(Main ${SOURCE_LIST})

# Create the source groups for source tree with root at CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR.
source_group(TREE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} FILES ${SOURCE_LIST})
```

Answer (score 6):

I wanted to comment on https://stackoverflow.com/users/3987854/squareskittles 's answer, but I couldn't due to the lack of "reputation" ?

Anyway,

```
source_group(TREE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} FILES ${SOURCE_LIST})
```

works like a charm, but I also needed to set this:

```
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)
```

Answer (score 2):

I know that using the CMAKE glob function is usually frowned upon: [Why is CMAKE glob evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32411963/why-is-cmake-file-glob-evil%20%22Why%20is%20cmake%20glob%20evil?), but in *my* case I found it to better than explicitly naming each file. I figured I would include a modified version of Florian's answer using GLOB.

```
# This code sorts the project files as they appear in the root directory

# Generate a list of all .c & .h files in the current directory and sub directores.
file(
     GLOB_RECURSE source_list RELATIVE
     "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"
     *.c *.h
    )
foreach(source IN LISTS source_list)
    get_filename_component(source_path "${source}" PATH)
    string(REPLACE "/" "\\" source_path_msvc "${source_path}")
    source_group("${source_path_msvc}" FILES "${source}")
endforeach()  
message(STATUS "Tree reorganized")
```

Comment: This is just the same as accepted answer by Florian and is just as broken: produces filters for all the absolute paths like: E: > Code > Demo > Main > file.cpp & E: > Code > Demo > Main > Dir > file1.cpp.

Comment: This works for me, without producing broken filters. The only difference is I changed the code inside the foreach block to

    `cmake_path( NATIVE_PATH source native_source )`
    `cmake_path( GET native_source PARENT_PATH native_parent )`
    `source_group("${native_parent}" FILES "${source}")`