# How to keep source folders hierarchy on solution explorer?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2015, solution-explorer

I made a C++ project on Linux, and I grouped source files in many directories to organize myself.

I was using CMake to compile, with one CMakeFiles.txt on each subdirectory.

```
srcs
|--folderA
|  |--Toto.cpp
|  |--Tata.cpp
|
|--folderB
|  |--Foo.cpp
|  |--Bar.cpp
[...]
```

Recently, I opened it with Visual Studio 2015, which found every source file, but just put the entire list on the "Source Files" folder of solution explorer.

```
Source Files
|--Toto.cpp
|--Tata.cpp
|--Foo.cpp
|--Bar.cpp
```

I plan to have a huge number of files, and it shall be soon difficult to find one.

Is there any way to explicitly tell it to respect the folder hierarchy on solution explorer?

Comment: What version of CMake?

Comment: @JamesAdkison I'm using the last one, the 3.3.1.

Comment: I have added a `assign_source_group` example implementation you might find useful to my answer in [How to set Visual Studio Filters for nested sub directory using cmake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31422680/how-to-set-visual-studio-filters-for-nested-sub-directory-using-cmake/31423421#31423421).

Comment: @JamesAdkison Thanks to this, I made it. Problem solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`source_group`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/source_group.html) command.

> source_group(`<name>` [FILES `<src>...`] [REGULAR_EXPRESSION `<regex>`])
>
> Defines a group into which sources will be placed in project files. This is intended to set up file tabs in Visual Studio. The options are:
>
> FILES
>   Any source file specified explicitly will be placed in group . Relative paths are interpreted with respect to the current source directory.
>
> REGULAR_EXPRESSION
>   Any source file whose name matches the regular expression will be placed in group .

Answer (score 3):

@James Adkison is correct; `source_group` is what you want to use. As of CMake [3.8](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/command/source_group.html), the improved `source_group` command now offers a `TREE` argument to recursively search your source hierarchy to create source groups to match it. Here is a basic solution for the example you provided:

```
project(MyProj)

set(MyProj_SOURCES
    "folderA/Toto.cpp"
    "folderA/Tata.cpp"
    "folderB/Foo.cpp"
    "folderB/Bar.cpp"
)

add_executable(Main ${MyProj_SOURCES})

# Create the source groups for source tree with root at CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR.
source_group(TREE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} FILES ${MyProj_SOURCES})
```