# Display include-directory as separate part of project in Visual Studio using CMake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, cross-platform

I am in the process of porting a big library project from Linux to Windows. Fortunately we were using CMake even before porting was even remotely on the table so not many adjustments were needed.

I figured it might be a good idea to develop the Windows parts natively on Windows for easier testing so i created a VS Studio using the CMake-gui

My project is organized like this:

lib/ # Library source code
   include/
     mylib/ # Public installable header files

In the top CMakeLists.txt i added

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
```

so my internal source files include the headers just like an external application would.

The problem is now the following: Visual Studio 2015 displays the public header files in the "External References"-directory among a lot of system headers. It is not obvious which header files belong to the project.

How can i make VS display the public headers separately from the system includes?

Comment: All header files you want to be explicitly listed in Visual Studio projects have to be listed as a source file in your CMake target's list of sources. Then you can group those sources/headers via the `source_group(... REGULAR_EXPRESSION ...)` command. For more details see [Keeping file hierarchy across subdirectories in CMake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31538466/keeping-file-hierarchy-across-subdirectories-in-cmake) and [How to keep source folders hierarchy on solution explorer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32576434/how-to-keep-source-folders-hierarchy-on-solution-explorer).

Comment: If i were able to accept this comment as a correct answer, i'd do it. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome. Turned my comment into an answer. And I added an example implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer*

All header files you want to be explicitly listed by `CMake` in Visual Studio projects have to be listed as a source file in your `CMake` target's list of sources.

Then you can group those sources/headers via the [`source_group(... FILES/REGULAR_EXPRESSION ...)`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/source_group.html) command.

If you have more then one target and you don't want to add those steps manually every time, you could think about grouping them into a [`function()`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/function.html):

```
function(my_add_library _target)
    file(
        GLOB_RECURSE _header_list 
        RELATIVE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"
        "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*.h*"
    )
    add_library(${_target} ${ARGN} ${_header_list})
    target_include_directories(${_target} PRIVATE "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
    source_group("Public Headers" FILES ${_header_list})
endfunction(my_add_library)
```

**Note**:

- I'm using [`file(GLOB ...)`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/file.html) only to collect the headers, not the sources (see [Why is cmake file GLOB evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32411963/why-is-cmake-file-glob-evil))
- You could keep the [`include_directories()`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/include_directories.html) command in the main `CMakeLists.txt`, I just prefer the target specific [`target_include_directories()`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/target_include_directories.html) variant

For more details on grouping source/header files in `CMake` see:

- [Keeping file hierarchy across subdirectories in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31538466/keeping-file-hierarchy-across-subdirectories-in-cmake)
- [How to keep source folders hierarchy on solution explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32576434/how-to-keep-source-folders-hierarchy-on-solution-explorer)

And as a general reference:

- [What is the difference between "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}" and "." in INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30705284/what-is-the-difference-between-cmake-current-source-dir-and-in-include)